# Windows Authentication pop-up

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, browser, windows-authentication

When I try to use Windows auth, the pop-up tells me: X website required login for Y domain.

How can I hide the website name? And only show "You are required to login  first" text on that pop-up?

I cant' seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the popup for security reasons. That dialog is provided by the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, this is guaranteed to be impossible.

Otherwise, malicious websites in `<iframe>`s will steal your credentials by masquerading as a legitimate site.

Comment: hm, so there's no way to tell it to show less text? there's a strange text at the end: "The site says: [device name here]"